Set Mint Authority as PDA
I have written my code and tests in typescript to create a Token 2022 which I would like to have it's PDA be the mint authority. This was working using spl-token but it seems the function I am using now wants me to sign for the PDA when it is passed.
Here is the code snippet.
const mintTransaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: mint,
        space: mintLen,
        lamports: mintLamports,
        programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
    }),
    createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction(
        mint,
        mintAuthorityPubkey,
        mint,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
    ),
);


mintTransaction.add(
    createInitializeMintInstruction(mint, decimals, mintAuthorityPubkey, null, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID)
);

mintTransaction.add(
    createInitializeInstruction({
        programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        metadata: mint,
        updateAuthority: mint,
        mint: mint,
        mintAuthority: mintAuthorityPDA,
        name: metadata.name,
        symbol: metadata.symbol,
        uri: metadata.uri,
    })
)

const signers = [payer, mintKeypair]
const initSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, mintTransaction, signers, undefined);

How do I send set the token to allow minting with a PDA?

The mint authority needs to sign for the creation of metadata, so if your mint authority is a PDA, then you need an on-chain program that can sign for that PDA using invoke_signed.
I'm not sure about what you're trying to do, but it might be easier to use a normal keypair when initializing the mint and metadata, and then setting the mint authority to a PDA after you're done using set-authority on the token program.

Here is an example of an Anchor program instruction that creates a token2022 mint account with the metadata extension enable. You can use it as a starting point and update it to use a PDA as the mint authority.
Here is an example of an Anchor program using the original token program to create a mint with a PDA as the mint authority and mints tokens through a program. You can use this as a reference for how to sign for cross program invocations using PDA seeds.
